# compiling multiple .cpp files in a Qt application

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator

I have just started learning Qt and compiled and executed this spinet

```
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qlabel.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QLabel *label = new QLabel("Linux is wonderful", 0);
app.setMainWidget(label);
label->show();
return app.exec();
}
```

I made it run using following steps :
qmake -project

qmake .pro file

make

But here this code will be written in a single .cpp file , so i want to ask how large projects 
are handled when there are more than one .cpp files. In case of multiple .cpp files what steps are followed to compile and execute. Pls explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For multiple .cpp files, your .pro file should have something like this in it:

```
SOURCES = main.cpp otherfile.cpp yet_another_file.cpp
```

... a lot of people will spread it out across multiple lines, like this, to make it easier to read:

```
SOURCES = main.cpp \
          otherfile.cpp \ 
          yet_another_file.cpp
```

Comment: If you want to append files to SOURCES, you can use += ... if you want to set SOURCES to the specified values (and don't care about keeping what was previously in it), = will suffice.

Comment: Jeremy has it spot on to your question, john, however I find that manually working with the .pro file to be tedious and annoying, especially when using SubVersion and organizing a bunch files into respective directories, which creator also handles nicely. Though I still can't seem to get Creator to nicely move files around; i still do that manually :(

Answer (score 3):

I would advise using Qt Creator if you are using Qt. Creator provides easy management of your .pro file which is used to create the make file. It also includes a debugger which is extremely useful, among other things, including a form of Intellisense for those of us coming from MSVS.

In Creator, create a new Qt Desktop app, and go from there. Also, `Add New...` and `Add Existing...` are your friends.

Comment: Qt Creator is a great tool if you are new to Qt.